# Product of sums as sum of products

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, products

Let $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, and $x_{m,n}$ be the element in the $m$-th row and $n$-th column of the matrix. Is it possible to rewrite the product of sums $\prod_{m=1}^{M} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} x_{m, n}$ as a sum of products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I suspect the tough part is how to write such a summation.

In the $3 \times 2$ case, the sum is 
\begin{align*}
(x_{11} + x_{21})(x_{21} + x_{22})(x_{31} + x_{32}) &= 
  x_{11}x_{21}x_{31} 
+ x_{12}x_{21}x_{31} 
+ x_{11}x_{22}x_{31} 
+ x_{12}x_{22}x_{31} \\ 
&+ x_{11}x_{21}x_{32} 
+ x_{12}x_{21}x_{32} 
+ x_{11}x_{22}x_{32} 
+ x_{12}x_{22}x_{32},
\end{align*} certainly a sum of products, when expanded.

In general, a product like $(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{n})(b_1 + b_2 + \ldots + b_{n})\ldots (z_1 + z_2 + \ldots + z_n)$ of $m$ factors expands into a sum of products: one term for each selection $(a_{i_1}, b_{i_2}, \ldots, z_{i_m})$. In short, you just make $m$ selection of indices, each being selected from $n$ possible indices. Thus, each function $f: \{1, 2, \ldots, m\} \to \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ uniquely identifies a term in the product.

If we use the notation $[M] = \{1, 2, \ldots, M\}$ and $[N] = \{1, 2, \ldots, N\}$, the set of all functions $f: [M] \to [N]$ is usually denoted $[N]^{[M]}$ (in part because there are $N^M$ such functions).

We may then write $\prod_{m=1}^{M} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} x_{m, n}$ as a sum indexed by these functions, namely, $$\sum_{f \in [n]^{[m]}} \prod_{m = 1}^M  x_{m,f(m)}$$

In the intro example, we can see all $8$ functions $f \in [2]^{[3]}$ showing up: The $x_{11}x_{21}x_{31}$ coming from the function that sends all of $1, 2$, and $3$ to $1$, then the $x_{12}x_{21}x_{31}$ corresponding to the function $f: 1 \mapsto 2,\, 2 \mapsto 1,\, 3 \mapsto 1$, and so on.

Comment: Is there an efficient way to generate the set of the functions to compute the indices in a computer? I'm looking for something that given the input matrix $X$ it returns a vector $\mathbf{p} \in \mathbb{R}^{N^M}$ where the $i$-th element $p_i$ would be the $i$-th product of the sum. In the example you gave that would be $p_2 = x_{1, 2} x_{2, 1} x_{3,1}$.

Comment: I don't know how efficient it is to implement, but these functions $[m] \to [n]$ are basically $m$-tuples of things in $[n]$ (elements of the Cartesian product $[n] \times [n] \times \dots \times [n]$ (with $m$ sets)). In the $[2]^{[3]}$ example, the function that sends everything to $1$ might be stored as $(1, 1, 1)$, the second function as $(2, 1, 1)$, etc, the tuple being $(f(1), f(2), \ldots, f(m))$. You'll have to figure out how you want to order them, as I'm not sure there's a "natural" way to line all of those $N^M$ functions up.

Comment: Afterthought: Oh, yeah, there's at least one sensible way to arrange them: Think of them as $m$-digit base-$n$ (technically $n +1$) numbers without the digit 0, essentially. So 111, 112, 113, 121, 122, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like$$\sum_{n_{1},\ldots,n_{M}=1}^{N}\prod_{m=1}^{M}x_{m,n_{m}}$$ should do the trick.

Comment: It's presumably equivalent to what I had in mind, but I can't say I've seen the notation $n_1, \ldots, n_M = 1$ or $n_m$.

Comment: Sorry, by this I mean that we have $M$ indices $n_{1}, n_{2},\ldots, n_{M}$ all going from $1$ to $N.$ The sum is a compact way of writing the $M$-tuple sum $$\sum_{n_{1}=1}^{N}\sum_{n_{2}=1}^{M}\cdots\sum_{n_{M}=1}^{N}.$$